# Symfony API Platform : file upload on update

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm stuck with something with API Platform and Vich Uploader for a PUT request, the POST is working juste fine.

Here is my header for MediaObject entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource(
 *     iri="http://schema.org/MediaObject",
 *     normalizationContext={
 *         "groups"={"media_object_read"}
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "post"={
 *             "controller"=CreateMediaObjectAction::class,
 *             "deserialize"=false,
 *             "security"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')",
 *             "validation_groups"={"Default", "media_object_create"},
 *             "openapi_context"={
 *                 "requestBody"={
 *                     "content"={
 *                         "multipart/form-data"={
 *                             "schema"={
 *                                 "type"="object",
 *                                 "properties"={
 *                                     "file"={
 *                                         "type"="string",
 *                                         "format"="binary"
 *                                     }
 *                                 }
 *                             }
 *                         }
 *                     }
 *                 }
 *             }
 *         },
 *         "get",
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "put"={"controller"=UpdateMediaObjectAction::class,
 *             "deserialize"=false,
 *             "security"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')",
 *             "validation_groups"={"Default", "media_object_update"},
 *             "openapi_context"={
 *                 "requestBody"={
 *                     "content"={
 *                         "multipart/form-data"={
 *                             "schema"={
 *                                 "type"="object",
 *                                 "properties"={
 *                                     "file"={
 *                                         "type"="string",
 *                                         "format"="binary"
 *                                     }
 *                                 }
 *                             }
 *                         }
 *                     }
 *                 }
 *             }},
 *     "delete"={
 *          "security"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')"
 *     }
 *     }
 * )
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class MediaObject
{...}
```

In swagger it throws an error because the file is not attached to the request. It strange because I have exactly the same file input field, with just an ID parameter added.

Someone has manage to do that ?

Answer (score 5):

Found solution by myself !

Finally, the problem is that PHP does'nt handle well file in FormData on PUT, but well on POST.

So if you got the same issue change to  "method"="POST" in the "put" part from itemOperations.